# NSRegularExpression error: Get into when false

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a problem with NSRegularExpression. I'm sure that is my mistake, but i can't figure it out. I have this code:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
                              regularExpressionWithPattern: nextModelName
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:objTmplName options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [objTmplName length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    NSLog(@"objTmplName:%@ nextModelName:%@",objTmplName,nextModelName);
  }];
```

And the output is:

```
2012-07-30 10:59:48.779 MyApp[8470:707] objTmplName:yaoygo nextModelName:\w*
2012-07-30 10:59:48.799 MyApp[8470:707] objTmplName:yaoygo nextModelName:yo*
2012-07-30 10:59:48.808 MyApp[8470:707] objTmplName:yaoygo nextModelName:yaoygo
```

Why it get into when `objTmplName = yaoygo` and `nextModelName:yo*` ?

What i want to do is when my objTmplName start with "yo..." it will be true, otherway this should be false. For example:

```
yooygo TRUE
yaygo FALSE
yayoyoyo FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2012-07-30 10:59:48.799 MyApp[8470:707] objTmplName:yaoygo nextModelName:yo*
>
> Why it get into when objTmplName = yaoygo and nextModelName:yo* ?

`yo*` means:

`y` followed by any number of `o` (possibly none).

If you want to force at least one `o`, use:

```
yo+
```

After your edit to the question:

try and use the regex: `^yo.*`

Comment: I'm update my question. This is not what i excatly what to do here.